# Installing NumPy with pip fails on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, pip

When I try:

```
$ sudo pip install numpy
```

on my Ubuntu 12.04 server, I get:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Tue Dec 10 18:25:54 2013
Downloading/unpacking numpy

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  URLs to search for versions for numpy:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/n/numpy/numpy-1.0.1.dev3460.win32-py2.4.exe#md5=a55b13b1f141de2aa965d5c5554c4ad8 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.3.0.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=28ee6681b04beb5bfc4bc056417ff087 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.win32-py2.5-nosse.exe#md5=bfcb66706ebdece6a9680f79f2b643ca (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.5/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.win32-py2.5.exe#md5=539782c7311d4a3379f66a964159ef11 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    [ ...SNIP...]
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=a6b66602e72436db37e6edbbce269fdf (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=b98cc04b20347127e297a99b6114b514 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=1b12834a53d3ba543d41399c40b5b791 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.2/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py3.2.exe#md5=651465cacf107d254ddcefcebb47064d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=4f20740e7e9d31a9d4c1636a931bc3f9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.3/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py3.3.exe#md5=6519c7bb198d0caf2913469883a63be9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/); unknown archive format: .exe
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.3.0.tar.gz#md5=3f7773ff0971a5ebb8591536d8ec7bd6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.3.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.4.1.tar.gz#md5=89b8a56e018b634f7d05c56f17bc4943 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.4.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.0.tar.gz#md5=3a8bfdc434df782d647161c48943ee09 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.5.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=376ef150df41b5353944ab742145352d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.5.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.tar.gz#md5=e0993c74cb8e83292e560eac1a9be8e9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.0.zip#md5=f0ce7ea1a12b3b3480571980af243e48 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.tar.gz#md5=2bce18c08fc4fce461656f0f4dd9103e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.1.zip#md5=462c22b8eb221c78ddd51de98fbb5979 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.tar.gz#md5=95ed6c9dcc94af1fc1642ea2a33c1bba (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.6.2.zip#md5=7e13c931985f90efcfa0408f845d6fee (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.6.2
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.tar.gz#md5=4fa54e40b6a243416f0248123b6ec332 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.0.zip#md5=ca27913c59393940e880fab420f985b4 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.tar.gz#md5=0ab72b3b83528a7ae79c6df9042d61c6 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.zip#md5=9a72db3cad7a6286c0d22ee43ad9bc6c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.7.1
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.tar.gz#md5=2a4b0423a758706d592abb6721ec8dcd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.8.0
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.zip#md5=6c918bb91c0cfa055b16b13850cfcd6e (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/), version: 1.8.0
  Using version 1.8.0 (newest of versions: 1.8.0, 1.8.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.1, 1.3.0)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/numpy/numpy-1.8.0.tar.gz#md5=2a4b0423a758706d592abb6721ec8dcd (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy

    Running from numpy source directory.

    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found

    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

    F2PY Version 2

    blas_opt_info:

    blas_mkl_info:

      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

      NOT AVAILABLE



    openblas_info:

      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

      NOT AVAILABLE



    atlas_blas_threads_info:

    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

      NOT AVAILABLE



    atlas_blas_info:

      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

      NOT AVAILABLE



    /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1522: UserWarning:

        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

        the ATLAS environment variable.

      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

    blas_info:

      libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

      NOT AVAILABLE



    /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1531: UserWarning:

        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

        the BLAS environment variable.

      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

    blas_src_info:

      NOT AVAILABLE



    /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1534: UserWarning:

        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

      NOT AVAILABLE



    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found

    non-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'

    lapack_opt_info:

    lapack_mkl_info:

    mkl_info:

      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

      NOT AVAILABLE



      NOT AVAILABLE



    atlas_threads_info:

    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info

      NOT AVAILABLE



    atlas_info:

      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info

      NOT AVAILABLE



    /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1428: UserWarning:

        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

        the ATLAS environment variable.

      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

    lapack_info:

      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

      NOT AVAILABLE



    /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1439: UserWarning:

        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

        the LAPACK environment variable.

      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

    lapack_src_info:

      NOT AVAILABLE



    /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1442: UserWarning:

        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

      NOT AVAILABLE



    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

      warnings.warn(msg)

    running egg_info
    running build_src
    build_src

    building py_modules sources

    creating build
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy
    creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/distutils
    building library "npymath" sources

    customize Gnu95FCompiler

    Could not locate executable gfortran

    Could not locate executable f95

    customize IntelFCompiler

    Could not locate executable ifort

    Could not locate executable ifc

    customize LaheyFCompiler

    Could not locate executable lf95

    customize PGroupFCompiler

    Could not locate executable pgfortran

    customize AbsoftFCompiler

    Could not locate executable f90

    Could not locate executable f77

    customize NAGFCompiler

    customize VastFCompiler

    customize CompaqFCompiler

    Could not locate executable fort

    customize IntelItaniumFCompiler

    Could not locate executable efort

    Could not locate executable efc

    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler

    customize GnuFCompiler

    Could not locate executable g77

    customize G95FCompiler

    Could not locate executable g95

    customize PathScaleFCompiler

    Could not locate executable pathf95

    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'

    C compiler: gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC



    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'

    gcc: _configtest.c

    sh: 1: gcc: not found

    sh: 1: gcc: not found

    failure.

    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py", line 192, in <module>

        setup_package()

      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py", line 185, in setup_package

        configuration=configuration )

      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup

        return old_setup(**new_attr)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

        dist.run_commands()

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

        self.run_command(cmd)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 10, in run

        self.run_command("build_src")

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

        self.distribution.run_command(command)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

        cmd_obj.run()

      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run

        self.build_sources()

      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources

        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)

      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources

        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))

      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources

        source = func(extension, build_dir)

      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 674, in get_mathlib_info

        raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")

    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Running from numpy source directory.

/bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found

non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



openblas_info:

  libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1522: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

blas_info:

  libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1531: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting

    the BLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

blas_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1534: UserWarning:

    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting

    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

  NOT AVAILABLE



/bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found

non-existing path in 'numpy/lib': 'benchmarks'

lapack_opt_info:

lapack_mkl_info:

mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1428: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

lapack_info:

  libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1439: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting

    the LAPACK environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)

lapack_src_info:

  NOT AVAILABLE



/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1442: UserWarning:

    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.

    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting

    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.

  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)

  NOT AVAILABLE



/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'

  warnings.warn(msg)

running egg_info

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

creating build

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy

creating build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/distutils

building library "npymath" sources

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Could not locate executable gfortran

Could not locate executable f95

customize IntelFCompiler

Could not locate executable ifort

Could not locate executable ifc

customize LaheyFCompiler

Could not locate executable lf95

customize PGroupFCompiler

Could not locate executable pgfortran

customize AbsoftFCompiler

Could not locate executable f90

Could not locate executable f77

customize NAGFCompiler

customize VastFCompiler

customize CompaqFCompiler

Could not locate executable fort

customize IntelItaniumFCompiler

Could not locate executable efort

Could not locate executable efc

customize IntelEM64TFCompiler

customize GnuFCompiler

Could not locate executable g77

customize G95FCompiler

Could not locate executable g95

customize PathScaleFCompiler

Could not locate executable pathf95

don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'

C compiler: gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c'

gcc: _configtest.c

sh: 1: gcc: not found

sh: 1: gcc: not found

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py", line 192, in <module>

    setup_package()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/setup.py", line 185, in setup_package

    configuration=configuration )

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup

    return old_setup(**new_attr)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 10, in run

    self.run_command("build_src")

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run

    self.build_sources()

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 164, in build_sources

    self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 299, in build_library_sources

    sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources

    source = func(extension, build_dir)

  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 674, in get_mathlib_info

    raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")

RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

----------------------------------------

Cleaning up...

  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1134, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 259, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 670, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/numpy
```

I have no idea what I need to do to fix this. Eventually I would be able to put all dependencies that I need in a `requirements.txt` file, so that I can install devendencies in a `virtualenv`. With that in mind, I would prefer a solution that uses `pip` as opposed to `apt-get` or installing from source.

Comment: Any specific reason why you prefer `pip`? `apt-get` is tailored for your system, and thus installs the version that best fits the environment/OS.

Comment: @JamesMills I disagree - I have found build instructions for NumPy poorly and inconsistently documented.

Comment: @MrE Yeah sorry this is not my experience at all. Maybe I've just done this a lot over the years.

Comment: @JamesMills no worries :)

Comment: @Evert I prefer `pip` so that all of my dependencies for a project (with versions specified) can be contained in a text file `requirements.txt` so that the source code of the project gives all that is necessary to deploy, and in a standard way.

Comment: Experienced the same issue on a remote 14.04 server, and apt-get installing python-dev solved it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems like your system does not have `gcc`.

Install build tools using following command:

```
apt-get install build-essential python-dev
```

Answer (score 9):

`pip` won't install the necessary compilers for you.

If you simply want numpy, and don't need to go through pip, use

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

For Python 3 packages version:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

and you'll get all the requisites as well (such as `python-dev`).

Comment: Which is the whole point of having a server (this is 12.04 server, which if I'm correct is LTS): it may get outdated because of the pace of development (of Python, numpy etc), but as a complete system, it should be very steady. Upgrading packages by hand works, up to a point, and then things can fall over rapidly.

Answer (score 8):

Some of these packages may not be required (don't have time to check in detail) but in a setup script of mine to install the NumPy stack I install the following Ubuntu packages first:

```
- build-essential
- gfortran
- libatlas-base-dev
- libatlas3gf-base
- python-dev
- libjpeg-dev
- libxml2-dev
- libfreetype6-dev
- libpng-dev
```

Otherwise you could simply use the Anaconda Python distribution, which works great.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get almost same type of errors but solved it using a virtual environment. There are many environments but I personally suggest venv.

I was able to easily get rid of the errors using venv.

It is because loading all libraries on OS using `sudo` is not appropriate.
Your OS becomes big and gives unwanted errors.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you do not have access to any internet, then try downloading its dependencies too  manually like intel_Openmp, MKL,MKL_include and MKL-devel first and then install numpy