# Using Module for different python version

Tags: python, linux, numpy, module

The default version of python (ie, one that opens on typing "python" in command line) is 2.6 on my server. I also have 2.7 installed. How do I import a module, in this case numpy, in python2.7? When I try to import right now, it gives me an error -

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Is there any workaround, apart from downloading the package and doing a build install?

Comment: you have to copile numpy separately for python2.7 you can use pip for that. "/path/to/python2.7/bin/pip install numpy". If this doesn't work follow this - http://www.scipy.org/install.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497339/installing-numpy-with-pip-fails-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks! I just did what you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comment above. You will have to compile it separately. I once tried a hack of importing and modifying the sys.path however I ran into issues with the .so files.