# Cannot install numpy in virtual env python 3.6

Tags: numpy, pip, virtualenv, python-3.6, raspbian

I have tried `pip install numpy` and `pip install numpy==1.13.3` and I keep getting this error:

```
 Command "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/venv_python36/bin/python3.6 -u -c
 "import setuptools,
 tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-f4w3ieb6/numpy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
 '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install
 --record /tmp/pip-ngusfvpy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/.virtualenvs/venv_python36/include/site/python3.6/numpy"
 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-f4w3ieb6/numpy/
```

It works fine on python 3.5

Full log: https://pastebin.com/Jah0FVcc (too long to post)

Comment: Please post the full output returned after `pip install numpy`. There are more clues in there. (See for example how the output led to an answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20497339/190597).)

Comment: @unutbu updated

Answer (score 1):

`pip install -U setuptools` fixed the problem and I was able to install numpy without issues

Comment: had to do this and also run `pip install -U pip` for me to install numpy on a virtualenv.